# URL Rewriting Using .htaccess for PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want to convert this URL `example.com/post.php?id=12345&title=xyz` to `example.com/12345/xyz`.

I am able to do `example.com/12345` but I can't get `/xyz`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

This solution assumes that you are hitting `example.com/post.php?id=12345&title=xyz` sample url in browser and want to change it to `example.com/12345/xyz`

```
##Enabling engine here.
RewriteEngine ON
##Extrenal redirect 301 to mentioned url by OP in question.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/post\.php\?id=([^&]*)&title=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to post.php with query strings.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```